# How to sum a field for two times with two conditions in the same SQL Statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL statements:

```
Select SUM (amount) from accounts Where acctype = 0;
```

and

```
Select SUM (amount) from accounts Where acctype = 1;
```

I want to find the difference between the amount in two cases in a single SQL statement.

Comment: If you like "hacks": `Select SUM(amount * sign(acctype - 0.5)) from accounts Where acctype in (0,1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  SUM(case when acctype = 0 then amount else 0 end) AS sum0,
  SUM(case when acctype = 1 then amount else 0 end) AS sum1,
  SUM(case when acctype = 0 then amount else 0 end) -
  SUM(case when acctype = 1 then amount else 0 end) AS diff
FROM accounts;
```

Comment: Can we use something like - WHERE acctype BETWEEN 0 AND 1 ;. Asking for my knowledge.

Comment: @Belle: Yes, you can use an additional `WHERE` clause, which may even get the result faster. I'd rather use `WHERE acctype IN (0, 1)`, though, as I consider this clearer (we are only interested in the values 0 and 1, no values between the two).

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when acctype = 0 then amount
                when acctype = 1 then - amount
           end) as diff
from accounts;
```

Comment: Far be it form me, but I think you are missing an `end` in that case

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Your Answer is correct, and as RiggsFolly said, we must put End at the end before as diff, anyway thank you so much and please put the "End" to make the code correct

Comment: @Hamada: this solution is probably more efficient than computing two distinct `sum()`s and substracting them.